# В чем заключается ошибка и как ее исправить?

Tags: python

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      warning: src\gevent\resolver\cares.pyx:38:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-
place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\resolver\cares.pyx:40:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-
place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\resolver\cares.pyx:41:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-
place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      Compiling src/gevent/resolver/cares.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/resolver/cares.pyx
      warning: src\gevent\libev\corecext.pyx:325:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in
-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\libev\corecext.pyx:783:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in
-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\libev\corecext.pyx:785:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in
-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\libev\corecext.pyx:787:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in
-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      warning: src\gevent\libev\corecext.pyx:791:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in
-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
      Compiling src/gevent/libev/corecext.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/libev/corecext.pyx
      Compiling src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py
      Compiling src/gevent/_hub_primitives.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_hub_primitives.py
      Compiling src/gevent/_hub_local.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_hub_local.py
      Compiling src/gevent/_waiter.py because it changed. 
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_waiter.py
      warning: src\gevent\_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:112:33: Declarations should not be declared inline.
     
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef load_traceback
      cdef Waiter
      cdef wait
      cdef iwait
      cdef reraise
      cpdef GEVENT_CONFIG
            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
     
      src\gevent\_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:181:6: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      Compiling src/gevent/greenlet.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/greenlet.py
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module> 
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel  
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 482, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 287, in <module> 
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-upohirk4\gevent_13663d571e1442618d98996674684c89\_setuputils.py", line 236, in cythonize1
          new_ext = cythonize(
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1129, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4df4o023\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1296, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: src/gevent/greenlet.py
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: данный вопрос нужно конкретезировать, и предоставить минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1801